# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception [Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway]

Tags: flutter

I have just upgrading my flutter to 3.3.6. However, I could not build APK file

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:adcolony-adapter:0.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:adcolony-adapter:0.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/adcolony-adapter/0.5.0/adcolony-adapter-0.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/adcolony-adapter/0.5.0/adcolony-adapter-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:applovin-adapter:0.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:applovin-adapter:0.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/applovin-adapter/0.5.0/applovin-adapter-0.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/applovin-adapter/0.5.0/applovin-adapter-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:vungle-adapter:0.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:vungle-adapter:0.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/vungle-adapter/0.5.0/vungle-adapter-0.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/vungle-adapter/0.5.0/vungle-adapter-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:facebook-adapter:0.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:facebook-adapter:0.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/facebook-adapter/0.5.0/facebook-adapter-0.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/facebook-adapter/0.5.0/facebook-adapter-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:admob-adapter:0.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.unity3d.mediation:admob-adapter:0.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/admob-adapter/0.5.0/admob-adapter-0.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/unity3d/mediation/admob-adapter/0.5.0/admob-adapter-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

This is my build.gradle files. I even have replaced with mavenCentral()

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have no idea why it went errors. It seems that the problem comes with this package
https://pub.dev/packages/unity_mediation

However, I have updated it the new version.